# CMYK printing: each color at 100% fill on color laser printer

Tags: printing, laser-printer, cmyk, color-printer

I want to buy a color laser printer. One of the main purposes will be printing on transparent films and I need as more as possible opaque printing.

So I need to reach 100% fill for each color at one area. Сan it be any color laser printer or just only some printers have a possibility to "overprint" areas by each color toner? Where to find an information about this possibility? 
Does it hardware/driver dependend or printing software only? Which software will allow me to print 100% each color on the same area? 
I mean that I can prepare a PDF file with some figures with C100M100Y100K100 fills for example in CorelDraw, but should I have CorelDraw on printing computer, or for example Acrobat Reader will be enough?

Comment: I don't think that any printers allow multiple passes past the drum for the same colour, so for overprinting you pay beed to re-load the trasnparency and print it again.

Comment: I do not mean the same color, but different colors. Any color laser printer passes paper or film sheet sequently via all 4 drums, so theoretically I can get 100% fill for each toner. Byt I doubd, maybe some drivers/firmware restrict this possibility and do not allow 400% fill summary